# Are there any style guides for Chinese?

Tags: books, reference-materials

There are many different style guides for English, such as *The Chicago Manual of Style* and *MLA Style Manual and Guide to Scholarly Publishing*. Are there similar publications available for Chinese? Although I do not need this specifically in academics, I need a general reference for preparing documents for publication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three similar style guides for Chinese:

1. [文后参考文献著录规则 GB/T 7714-2005](http://www.lib.tsinghua.edu.cn/service/SCIcenter/ip/standard-7714.pdf)　[Appendix A](http://www.lib.tsinghua.edu.cn/service/SCIcenter/ip/standard-7714-A.pdf)　[Appendix B](http://www.lib.tsinghua.edu.cn/service/SCIcenter/ip/standard-7714-B.pdf)
2. [科学技术报告、学位论文和学术论文的编写格式 GB7713-87](http://www.lib.tsinghua.edu.cn/service/GB7713-87.doc)
3. [文摘编写规则 GB 6447-86](http://www.lib.tsinghua.edu.cn/service/GB6447-86.doc)

Answer (score 3):

There's a modern copywriting guide for Chinese:

中文文案排版指北 https://github.com/sparanoid/chinese-copywriting-guidelines